# iOS - Best practice to get async properties of collection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, collections, phasset

While working with `PHAsset` in Swift, I am facing a common problem which must have a good design/solution. For example, I have a collection of `PHAsset`, lets say `assetCollection`. Now I want to get total size of the `assetCollection` which is the sum of all assets in it.

I know there is a asynchronous API to get individual asset size  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551990/1084174 (in objective-c),

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
        float imageSize = imageData.length;
        //convert to Megabytes
        imageSize = imageSize/(1024*1024);
        NSLog(@"%f",imageSize);
 }];
```

But when its a collection how do I design the solution?

What's in my mind is, I can run async call inside a loop for each asset in `assetCollection` summing sizes in `total` variable until when I get the last result (may be using global variable). `total` will be the final collection size. But I think there must be some better design/solution to such common problem.

It would be appreciated if anyone suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending weeks i have come to a better solution. I am sharing my solution but still there might be some better design. Please share if you get any better.

#### Solution

I create a wrapper collection, let's say `sizedAssetCollection` with a property called `size`. I also implement `add()` and `remove()` methods. When I add or remove an item through my add/remove method i calculate update the `size` on the fly. Like,

```
void add (PHAsset *asset) {
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
        float imageSize = imageData.length;
        imageSize = imageSize/(1024*1024);
        size += imageSize;
 }];
}


void remove(PHAsset *asset) {
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
        float imageSize = imageData.length;
        imageSize = imageSize/(1024*1024);
        size -= imageSize;
 }];
}
```

Finally I get the expected result in `size` variable.